# Replacing an old ActionListener for a button with a new one

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I was wondering (if possible) how I could update what a JButton's ActionListener performs. I need to keep one button throughout my whole program, but change what it does depending on the current situation.

Comment: Take a look at the [Action API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first use removeActionListener() than add new one.
Use getActionListeners method to get list of all action listeners for your button.